# There's no pressure, just follow at your own pace or There's no pressure, just follow your own pace?

Tags: word-usage

It's one of the introduction pages for a flash card application and I'm try to convey the message that people can use the app at their own speed. Would it be better to say:

There's no pressure, just follow at your own pace

There's no pressure, just follow your own pace

Comment: It is pressuring to mention that there's no pressure. The flash cards are simply *self-paced* and *untimed*.

Comment: @Robusto The ELU beach or mine? But thanks for the heads-up. ... ... Hmm. Aren't brain cramps one of the signs of ...?